# How can I check if my OS X application can connect to a specific server-- assuming there is internet connection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, afnetworking

I currently am using AFNetworking to determine if my application has network reachability.

```
NSNumber *s = notification.userInfo[AFNetworkingReachabilityNotificationStatusItem];
   AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = [s integerValue];

   if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi) {
```

**But**, now I also need to know if my application can reach a specific server.  More specifically, the server I am connecting to may be down and I need a way to determine if this is the case, from the client side, so I can notify my users appropriately.

It's a very tough google because all searches I do just point me to "How to determine network reachability".  Has anybody dealt with this before, and have a solution in mind?

**EDIT:** @AvT recommended a promising looking solution, so I tried it like this:

```
   self.testTSCReachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.asdasfjsldfkjslefjslkjslfs.com"];
   __weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
   [self.testReachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
      if (weakSelf.testReachabilityManager.reachable) {
         NSLog(@"YES");
      }
      else
      {
         NSLog(@"NO");
      }

   }];
```

But unfortunately, it is logging out "YES" for me, even after I have confirmed it is most definitely not reachable.

Comment: Try to connect to the server. If you can't, it isn't reachable.

Comment: For whatever reason, that simple comment made me totally want to slap myself.  I was stuck thinking in AFNetworking how I could make a check.  But I should just use `NSURLConnection` to initialize a request, and check the status of the response right?

Comment: Sure, if it fails you'll time out in good order. - That is the whole nature of the network. You don't know until you try. Even then you don't "know" anything; servers come and go constantly. You just have to roll with the punches.

Comment: Please check your code. You use two different reachability mangers in the last sample: `testTSCReachabilityManager ` and `testReachabilityManager `.

Comment: Ah sorry that is an artifact of edits I made to put the code on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate AFNetworkReachabilityManager with class method

```
+ (instancetype)managerForDomain:(NSString *)domain;
```

and pass string with the required domain. AFNetworkReachabilityManager will check reachability of this domain.

If `serverURL` is an url of your server you should use it the following way:

```
[AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:serverURL.host]
```

**Update**
Following code works as expected:

```
static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *testTSCReachabilityManager;
testTSCReachabilityManager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.asdasfjsldfkjslefjslkjslfs.com"];
[testTSCReachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    if (testTSCReachabilityManager.reachable) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
}];
[testTSCReachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

Comment: Hey @Avt, thanks for the answer :)  I tried to play around with that, and edited my question with my attempt-- but I'm not getting what I want.  Can you see at first glance if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @MattyAyOh What is AFNetworkReachabilityStatus in callback block?

Comment: @MattyAyOh also please note that `reachable` does only mean that the server is reachable over the network. It does not mean that it is running or working as expected.

Comment: Right, I just want to check if it's reachable.  I can check the status tomorrow at work ^^  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Update: I actually ended up going w/ a different implementation than what Avt recommended, and did what matt recommended in the comments instead

I created an `NSURLRequest` and make a request to my server, then used the delegate callbacks to determine if the server was reachable.  Works like a charm

```
-(void)checkConnectionToServers
{
   NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];

   request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myserver.com"] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)5.0];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
   [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"FAIL");
}
```